# Added menu item to the main menu through INavigationProvider but it won't show?

Tags: orchardcms

Using Orchard cms 1.5.1 I have created a module which contains controller that fetches list from a web service.
I want to add a menu item in main menu when this module is enabled. For that i have created 
MainMenu as follows:

```
public class MainMenu:INavigationProvider
{
    public Localizer T { get; set; }
    public String MenuName
    {
        get { return "main"; }
    }
    public void GetNavigation(NavigationBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.Add(menu => menu.Add(T("Fetched List"), "4", item => item.Action("Index", "FetchedList")));
    }
}
```

When my module is enabled, navigation won't show that menu item. Am i doing something wrong?

Comment: When you put a breakpoint in GetNavigation, does it get hit?

Comment: GetNavigation in MainMenu doesn't get hit. 
Also, IEnumerable<MenuItem> BuildMenu(string menuName) in Orchard.UI.Navigation.NavigationManager gets hit only for 'admin' as menuName.

Comment: As there is no more Orchard.Core.Navigation.Services.MainMenuNavigationProvider which looks for "main" as explained by Piotr Szmyd in his article at http://www.szmyd.com.pl/blog/building-multi-level-menu-for-orchard#.UB_jQPbN8u8 i think it is obsolete to implement INavigationProvider to attach menu items to Main Menu. Should I use IMenuProvider instead?

Comment: Yes, for the main menu, things changed in 1.5 and you should base your code on the new menu item providers that come with the system.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From Orchard 1.5.0 onwards, `INavigationProvider` isn't used to build menus on the front end (it is still used to build the admin menu for the Dashboard though). You need to implement either `IMenuProvider` or `INavigationFilter`. [See this post on David Hayden's blog for some pointers](http://www.davidhayden.me/blog/dynamically-injecting-menu-items-in-orchard-cms). You can also find good examples in both [Orchard.Projections](http://orchardprojections.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/a2ed93910303#Navigation/NavigationQueryProvider.cs), and [Orchard.CulturePicker](http://orchardculturepicker.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/2621084ed8e7#Services/LocalizableMainMenuNavigationFilter.cs).

Comment: Implementing INavigationFilter to add menu items does not seem to be the proper way of doing it, as it is or seems like a filter. Orchard.Core.Navigation.Services.DefaultMenuProvider implements IMenuProvider as should be, but if i implement it and there are more than one menu roots, my module will attach items to all of them. Any suggestions?

Comment: Correct, `IMenuProvider` is used to add completely new items to the menu, whereas `INavigationFilter` is used to expand content items like `NavigationQueryMenuItem` into it's component parts (e.g. if you using a projection to populate a portion of the menu), so really it depends on how you want to inject your menu items. `IMenuProvider.GetMenu()` takes a `menu` parameter, can you not use that to differentiate between root menus?

Comment: Will try it. Thanks Matt and Bertrand for your valuable inputs.

Comment: @timoffei @mdm Exactly - since 1.5 the code-based navigation providers had been split into `INavigationProvider` (for admin) and `IMenuProvider` (for all other menus). Usage of either one is the proper way of adding new items to the menu. `INavigationFilter` is used to alter the existing, already built menu (you can add items this way, of course, but it's just not the best practice).

Comment: link to blog entry is broken