# authenticable Menu Item in Orchard

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.9

I want to create an authentic-able Menu Item in Orchard.

I read this post and resources referenced:

[Added menu item to the main menu through INavigationProvider but it won't show?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11827737/added-menu-item-to-the-main-menu-through-inavigationprovider-but-it-wont-show)

http://www.szmyd.com.pl/blog/building-multi-level-menu-for-orchard#.UB_jQPbN8u8

But I can't Implement It's!;

can any body to describe with coding?!

Comment: A menu item in the frontend of the website or in the dashboard?

Comment: @devqon: in the front end(main Menu)... I don't need admin menu

Comment: Checkout this blogpost: https://www.cloudconstruct.com/blog/setting-permissions-on-custom-orchard-menu-links